# How to manage dependencies when developing OSGI bundle in Netbeans and Karaf?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I'm struggling to wrap my head around developing OSGI bundles to publish to Karaf.  I'm using Netbeans 7.4 and the Create Maven OSGI bundle when creating a new project.  I think what I'm wrestling with is dealing with dependencies between different projects and working with them in Netbeans and then publishing to Karaf.

What I'm trying to do is set up a REST web service; I found [this tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi) to be a good starting point in getting something basic up and running.  So I started setting up a parent project with sub projects (all of these are from the Maven OSGI Bundle template).  But after I started deploying bundles to my Karaf instance I started wrestling with the "missing requirement" errors within Karaf.  I'd start trying to list each dependency in `<Export-Package>` or `<Embed-Dependency>` but it seems like I just keep going farther down and always getting new "missing requirement" messages listing yet another dependency.  I then started trying the maven copy-dependencies plugin to export whatever dependencies are used in my project and copying whatever comes out into the Karaf deploy folder, too.  That worked for the most part but I'm wrestling with what I think are downstream dependencies of a 3rd party jar, but that's probably a separate question anyway.

So, what I'd like to know is how should I be developing a coherent "application" with this setup?  I understand I should separate everything into standalone bundles; i.e., I'll have my REST interface as one, the implementation as another, business logic as another.  As a maven project, if I have a dependency for datetime handling or string utilities, maven will handle resolving all of those.  But these dependencies won't automatically be included in my OSGI bundle, is that the case? What is the workflow to make sure that everything my project depends on is available to the bundles in Karaf?  What about my projects that have other projects as dependencies, i.e., an interface implementation? I would include that project as a dependency so it will compile, but how do I make sure that that dependency is met after it is published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mismatch between dependencies at compile time and at deployment time is indeed a problem when working with OSGi.

What you need to know is how these relate to each other. At compile time you have the maven dependencies. When you build your project the maven bundle plugin creates the necessary Import-Package and Export-Package statements for you. Most of the time this simply works and you should avoid tuning too much there by hand.

So after the build the Manifest specifies what the resulting bundle needs but this does not automatically make sure the dependencies are met. So when you deploy the bundle to karaf you get the errors about missing dependencies. This is normal.

Now you need to install other bundles that fulfil these dependencies. Often you can simply install the jars of your maven dependencies (if they are bundles). This does not always work though. So basically you install the bundles and check if the requirements are met now.

The nice thing with karaf is that many bigger dependencies like cxf are already available as features. So it is a good idea to first try to get the dependencies by installing available features before you try to install them bundle by bundle.

So this helps you in getting your dependencies right. Then for "production" use the best solution is to create your own feature file where you refer to the bundles you found.

While installing bundles using the deploy dir seems nice at first it is not a good solution. Better install the bundles directly from maven using the mvn: url syntax karaf provides.

Regarding embedding dependencies. Sometimes it is a good solution but often it only makes things worse as it can lead to package use conflicts which are hard to solve. So better do not embed anything if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I think part of my problem was that one of my bundles is relying on a 3rd party jar that I'm having trouble making available in Karaf. I think this was throwing off some of the other bundles that were trying to use it.  It's making more sense for me now, but I'm probably going to open a new question specific to that issue.

One more then - in Karaf / OSGI, how are configuration variables handled? I.e., to develop against dev but then later point services to a production tier? Normally I'd use some sort of arguments or config file, but how does that work here?

Comment: In OSGi generally configurations are best handled using the Configuration Admin Service. In karaf this is mapped to config files in etc dir. I have written a tutorial about this: http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/G4Be

Comment: Thanks! I've walked through the sample, and have set up the blueprint settings and a .cfg file.  My setting is available within the Karaf console and I can modify it, but the change doesn't seem to be reflected in my bundle app. At least the refresh() method never appears to get fired. Is there a trick to reading a config value from within code? Is the pure OSGI wiring (ConfigUpdater) necessary if I'm configuring with Blueprint?

Comment: If you use blueprint then try to use the config admin namespace. It is described in the same tutorial a bit further down.