# How to get a working osgi-bundle with google-cloud-firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I am using [karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/) to create a modular project with different interfaces and bundles. Now i want to embed an interface to [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to use the realtime database.

I tried first to get a working java solution for firebase, which i find at [How to write data to firebase with a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906163/how-to-write-data-to-firebase-with-a-java-program).

Then i tried to bundle it with maven. My pom looks like

```
...

<dependencies>
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.76</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.rogatio.circlead.sunray.synchronizer.firebase.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.rogatio.circlead.sunray.synchronizer.firebase,
                        org.apache.karaf.util.tracker,
                        org.apache.karaf.util.tracker.annotation
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.google.appengine*
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>
                        *;scope=compile|runtime,
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Import-Package>
                        sun.misc;resolution:=optional,
                        com.sun.jdmk.comm;resolution:=optional,*
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    ...

</build>
```

It seems that the maven dependencies could not fully resolved for firebase-admin. The dependency hierarchy in Eclipse looks very huge for the google-api. So i searched and resolved one problem for the com.google.appengine.api by adding the appengine-sdk (found at https://community.openhab.org/t/problems-with-maven-dependencies-and-bnd/75750). Also i find a hint for the maven-bundle-plugin at [Google Client API in OSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191299/google-client-api-in-osgi) to solve some other missing dependencies.

But now i get another exception when i want to start the bundle in karaf. And for this exception i not found any solution

> Error starting bundle 58: Unable to resolve org.rogatio.circlead.sunray.circlead-synchronizer-firebase [58](R 58.0): missing requirement [org.rogatio.circlead.sunray.circlead-synchronizer-firebase [58](R 58.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.flogger.backend.android)

I not know what to do, to resolve this to get a working bundle. How can i get a working osgi-bundle for google-api or firebase-admin (which uses google-api)?

I think i not made a mistake by embedding for compiler or runtime (like explained at [How to manage dependencies when developing OSGI bundle in Netbeans and Karaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576188/how-to-manage-dependencies-when-developing-osgi-bundle-in-netbeans-and-karaf))

Comment: When I look at the firebase API it looks like one of those solutions that provide you with everything. These kind of tools typically have a hughe dependency chain. From personal experience I can only say. Stay away from this stuff in OSGi. If your really need access to it create a small microservice outside of OSGi that talks to firebase and let it talk to OSGi via a very simple e.g. REST API that covers just what you really need.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your tip and use as basis https://github.com/yamad/jaxrs-docker-example. I will link the result to github when i programmed it.

Comment: Hi community, i have a working solution which starts a firebase docker microservice from karaf and coresponds with karaf. At the moment i hold it in a closed project at gitlab. But if you like a solution then contact me.